# How can i make a turtle (player) carry another turtle (ball) when encountered and decides to carry it?

Tags: netlogo

i am trying to make a model that involves a turtle (player) picking up a ball (as turtle) when player reaches ball and decides to carry it.
Any related built-in functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tie`.

```
breed [balls ball]
breed [fetchers fetcher]

to setup
  ca
  create-balls 40 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set shape "circle"
  ]
  create-fetchers 1 [set size 2]
end

to go
  ask fetchers [move]
end

to move ;turtle proc
  set heading (heading - 45 + random 91)
  fd 1
  let _candidates balls-here
  if any? _candidates [
    create-link-with one-of _candidates [tie]
  ]
end
```

Comment: hi Alan, can i ask how can it be untie, upon reaching a defined patch?

Comment: ask the relevant tie to die

Comment: if you only ever have one tie (because there is only one ball and it is held by one player) then `ask links [die]`. But if you have multiple links then you need to identify the correct link(s) with something like `ask links with <whatever conditions> [die]`